# add a prefix to all lines of a dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a pandas dataframe 'correct_X_test' as mentioned :

```
index                                             review
2       38448  روايه سخيفه جدا. مش عارفه العيب منى ولا منها. ...
3       85548  أحمد مراد يتطور أسلوبه من رواية إلى أخرى.يحاول...
4      127165  كثيرا ما هربت من أنوثتي وكثيرا ما هربت منك لأن...
7       72234  ع عكس معظم الناس معجبنيش أوي. عجبني جداااا بعض...
8      150053  أحببت هذا الجزء أكثر .ذلك أن عرض الدكتور المسي...
...       ...                                                ...
31048   81162  الاسود يليق بك. لا اعرف كيف اصنفها. روايه روما...
31049  102431  تجتاحنى حالة من الهدوء النفسى عقب قراءة هذا ال...
31051  140999  اه ، كم لهذا الكتاب وقع في قلبي. قرأته بالوقت ...
31052  128882  تريد القيام برحله حول العالم برغم مكوثك بمكانك...
31053   85422  بالرغم من أنك قد تكون قرأت الكثير من الكتب الت...

[23005 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to add a prefix to the review columns.
Using this code the prefix is added to the index instead of the text as below:

```
Modified_X_test = correct_X_test["review"].add_prefix(' xxxx ')
print(Modified_X_test)
```

```
xxxx 2        روايه سخيفه جدا. مش عارفه العيب منى ولا منها. ...
 xxxx 3        أحمد مراد يتطور أسلوبه من رواية إلى أخرى.يحاول...
 xxxx 4        كثيرا ما هربت من أنوثتي وكثيرا ما هربت منك لأن...
 xxxx 7        ع عكس معظم الناس معجبنيش أوي. عجبني جداااا بعض...
 xxxx 8        أحببت هذا الجزء أكثر .ذلك أن عرض الدكتور المسي...
                                     ...                        
 xxxx 31048    الاسود يليق بك. لا اعرف كيف اصنفها. روايه روما...
 xxxx 31049    تجتاحنى حالة من الهدوء النفسى عقب قراءة هذا ال...
 xxxx 31051    اه ، كم لهذا الكتاب وقع في قلبي. قرأته بالوقت ...
 xxxx 31052    تريد القيام برحله حول العالم برغم مكوثك بمكانك...
 xxxx 31053    بالرغم من أنك قد تكون قرأت الكثير من الكتب الت...
Name: review, Length: 23005, dtype: object
```

Could you help me, please?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate your prefix with the desired column:

```py
df['review'] = 'xxx' + df['review']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior- [`.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) adds prefix to the *labels* (row labels if it's a series like `correct_X_test['review']`or`Modified_X_test`, column labels if it's a DataFrame like `correct_X_test`).

You could try something like

```py
correct_X_test["review_prefixed"] = [f' xxxx {r}' for r in list(correct_X_test["review"])]
```

And then `correct_X_test` will have an added column with prefixed `review`s.

Comment: `correct_X_test["review_prefixed"] = " xxxx " + correct_X_test["review"]` will do.

Comment: @ouroboros1 thanks! I didn't know that syntax (or maybe I forgot?) I'm used to using pandas only for saving the data at the last step